# How can I use "login: required" on a Google App Engine app using a custom domain?

Tags: google-app-engine

I have a Python GAE app on a custom domain. When I add login: required to any handler, the site redirects to the app's appspot.com domain instead of my custom domain. The functionality of the site isn't affected, and all handlers and routes continue to work as expected — just on the appspot.com domain instead.

Example snippet from the app.yaml below. mydomain.com works fine with the custom domain, mydomain.com/test and any other handlers redirect to the appspot.com domain after authentication (myapp.appspot.com/test).

```
- url: /
  script: main.application

- url: /test
  script: main.application
  login: required

- url: /.*
  script: main.application
  login: required
```

Is this a configuration issue with how App Engine is handling the domain, or is this an issue with the redirect used by the login: required setting?

Comment: I'm not sure I've had this issue but you can handle login redirects in your app with something like `if not users.get_current_user(): self.redirect(users.create_login_url(self.request.uri))`

Answer (score 1):

You need to set `Authorized redirect URIs` in your Developer Console (under API | Credentials) to your custom domain rather than the default appspot.com. So the requests coming from the custom domain would be 'called-back' to the custom domain as well.

Take a look on the attached screenshot on how this is configured for my application.

[[image: Redirect URI]]

Comment: This was helpful and led me down the right path — after more research, it looks like I'm using deprecated login URL functions, [documented here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/users/loginurls). I believe I'll need to implement OpenID Connect, as [mentioned here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/deprecations/open_id).

Comment: @SeanConnolly, glad to hear! Good luck!